# Jquery stops working after postback with a twist - need delegate with a find() selector

Tags: jquery, asp.net

So I see plenty of related questions, which shows me I'm on the right path with needing a delegate (.on()), I think.

I have this bit of jquery:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
                           $('.divGroupRowContent').find('.dxICheckBox').click(function (event) {
   alert('working properly');
   }
   })
```

Ignore any missing brackets/whatever, this is dumbed down for example's sake and I can't be fussed to properly terminate things right now. I'd rather write a whole bunch of words than deal with that currently.

Anyway, point being this works until the page does a postback for any number of reasons, at which point it ceases working. I assume this is because the controls are recreated and no longer have a client side handler associated with them.

I'm seeing a lot of answers with things like this

```
$('#idOfSomethingSurroundingThingWeNeedToClickOn').on('click', '.classOfThingWeNeedToClickOn or typeOfControl', function () {
                           alert('success');
                   });
```

Which is great, but I need to incorporate that find() in there. It doesn't seem to work tacked on in a direct swap. Also, does #idOfSomethingSurroundingThingWeNeedToClickOn need to be a direct parent? If a bunch of these controls are all regenerated how do I deal with that? Can I make that something like $(document)?

Winforms guy trying to make sense of it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, simply remove the find and combine the selector into one. I.e: `$('.divGroupRowContent').find('.dxICheckBox')` should be $`('.divGroupRowContent .dxICheckBox')`. This tells JQuery to find all class called *dxICheckBox* that are inside *divGroupRowContent*

You can find out more about JQuery from their [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Complete code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#idOfSomethingSurroundingThingWeNeedToClickOn').on('click', '.divGroupRowContent .dxICheckBox', function() {
        alert('success');
    })
});
```

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/oksupneb/1/

Comment: Thanks! Yeah the basics are always easy when switching languages and the documentation is great for that, that's how I landed on the find() function, but of course that's also how I ended up going down the wrong road. Looks like this is doing what I need.

Comment: Hey, wanted to ask a follow up - what's the best way to go about debugging why this wouldn't be working in practice? If I set up a simple example like this it's fine, but when my devexpress grid is adding the controls behind the scenes it isn't recognizing the delegate, I guess. Should I open a new question for this or can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: normally it's a new question, but for this it's fine. To debug the code you'll need something like Chome Dev Tools (press F12). You can either set the break point using the word debugger (lowercase on it's own line) or in dev tools: select source tab, find the JS code and next to the number (on the left) click & red dot becomes the break point.

Comment: In your code this selector $('#idOfSomethingSurroundingThingWeNeedToClickOn').on must be somethings that not dynamically loaded.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'm using firefox and chrome's dev tools - but I don't seem to be hitting the code at all, that's the issue I'm running into. I suspect the second comment hits on the real issue. The devexpress grid gets remade I think. In the fiddle it doesn't seem to matter how many layers down the code is though, so if I replace the #id with $(document) shouldn't that work (for reference, I tried, doesn't seem to be working either)? These are going to be the only things with that class combo on the page. Really been frustrating, working this problem for at least a week.

Comment: Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/x1bLuc45/. I have attached the click event to the body and added the div with class dxICheckBox dynamically afterwards. The click still works. Its most likely something weird with dev express.

Comment: Also if debugger is not working, then try console.log('some string'). It may be you're looking at a cached JavaScript?